# Bibliography entry for a volume of a book which has its own (sub-)title

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I am wondering how to use `biblatex` for a bibliographical entry for a book in two volumes which have (sub-)titles of their own. I am expecting something similar to the first entry in my exemplary output, but it seems a bit hackish. Maybe the technically correct way would be something like the second entry, but it looks to me like printing the subtitle before the title. Of course I can live with the first solution, but I'm curious, are these the two options I have or is there a better way which I missed?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book { snellgrove1959,
author = {David Snellgrove}, 
year = {1959},
title = {The Hevajra Tantra: A Critical Study, Part 2}, 
subtitle = {Sanskrit and Tibetan Texts},
location = {Oxford},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
}

@inbook { snellgrove1960, %Changed it to 1960 for the sake of the order.
author = {David Snellgrove}, 
year = {1960},
booktitle = {The Hevajra Tantra},
booksubtitle = {A Critical Study},
volume = {2}, 
%subtitle = {Sanskrit and Tibetan Texts}, %subtitle is not printed if there's no title
title = {Sanskrit and Tibetan Texts},
location = {Oxford},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The following is better than my original version with `@inbook`, but the order is still not what I had in mind. I guess it's not intended to be done like that.

```
@book { snellgrove1960, %Changed it to 1960 for the sake of the order.
author = {David Snellgrove},
year = {1960},
maintitle = {The Hevajra Tantra},
mainsubtitle = {A Critical Study},
volume = {2},
title = {Sanskrit and Tibetan Texts},
location = {Oxford},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
}
```

[image: output with book and maintitle]

Comment: I haven't really gotten around to properly have a look at this, but what about `maintitle` and friends? Plus there is also `@mvbook` as type (but that might be more interesting if you were to cite "Hevajra Tamtara" itself with no reference to any "sub-volume"), have a look at the `knuth:ct` works in [`biblatex-examples.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib)

Comment: @moewe See my edit.

Comment: Sorry but what is wrong with that output? That's what I would expect. You are citing a particular volume so the title of that volume comes first. I don't see what other order could make sense here?

Comment: That is just the way `biblatex-chicago` handles these kind of works. Since `biblatex-chicago` adheres to the rules of the CMS this seems to be a more or less sensible way to deal with such a case. Changing `chicago-authordate.bbx` to your wishes (i.e. swapping `title` and `maintitle`) looks a real hassle and will require to break some of the thought-through features of `biblatex-chicago`. Note that the standard `authoryear` style gives the order you seems to prefer.

Comment: Is there anything we can do about this question to get it off the unanswered list?

Answer (score 6):

This is the way `biblatex-chicago` handles multi-volume books, it displays the specific `title` of the volume first and then the general `maintitle` of the overall work.

> *Title*. Vol. X of *Maintitle*

The other possibility is to print the `maintitle` first and then the `title`

> *Maintitle*. Vol. X: *Title*

The latter seems to be what you want here, but the Chicago Manual of Style seems to think differently.

On a case-by-case basis it may turn out that the `maintitle`/`title` approach does not work. This is the case especially if the `maintitle` completely overshadows the volume `title`. In these cases it may turn out that writing everything into the `title` field is the only sensible solution.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{snellgrove1959,
  author    = {David Snellgrove}, 
  year      = {1959},
  title     = {The Hevajra Tantra: A Critical Study, Part 2}, 
  subtitle  = {Sanskrit and Tibetan Texts},
  location  = {London},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
}

@book{snellgrove1960,
  author       = {David Snellgrove}, 
  year         = {1960},
  maintitle    = {The Hevajra Tantra},
  mainsubtitle = {A Critical Study},
  volume       = {2}, 
  title        = {Sanskrit and Tibetan Texts},
  location     = {London},
  publisher    = {Oxford University Press},
}

@book{snellgrove1961,
  author       = {David Snellgrove}, 
  year         = {1961},
  maintitle    = {The Hevajra Tantra},
  mainsubtitle = {A Critical Study},
  part         = {2}, 
  title        = {Sanskrit and Tibetan Texts},
  location     = {London},
  publisher    = {Oxford University Press},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

A look at `chicago-authordate.bbx` tells me that you definitely don't want to start modifying the style to change from title-maintitle to maintitle-title. The current behaviour is rooted deep in the structure of the bibdrivers.